# checking if a record exist or not in php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to check that is there any record with given email address in database with this code in PHP, but when i have that email address in the database it says "doesnt exist"! whats the wrong with this code?

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","gvf_lingo","btrbghtre544","vtrbt_lingo");

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT user_email FROM rating WHERE user_email='testuser@gmail.com'");
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

      if ($num_rows > 0) {
        echo "exist";
      }else{
        echo "does not exist";
      }
```

Comment: `or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: 1. You haven't selected database with `mysql_select_db()`, so your query goes nowhere. 2. [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (_mysql_*_ functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (_mysqli_*_ functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: In fact, `new mysqli(...)` or `mysqli_connect(...)` accepts the DB name as a fourth parameter, yet `mysql_connect()` doesn't. Yet another advantage, albeit a minor one, of mysqli over mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_connect` requires 3 parameter, you passed 4 here, also you forgot to select Database here, you below code for this

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","gvf_lingo","btrbghtre544");
mysql_select_db("vtrbt_lingo",$con);
```

You can also use `mysqli` here like this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'your_username', 'your_password', 'your_db');
```

Answer (score 3):

You're giving incorrect connection string. Should be something,

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","gvf_lingo","btrbghtre544");
mysql_select_db("vtrbt_lingo",$con);
```

**Updated**

As *PleaseStand* mention in comment mysqli accept DB name as fourth parameter.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).